# What is the VBA syntax to specify a path in the BrowseForFolder function?

Tags: vba, outlook

Why would this line of code cause a syntax error in my Outlook VBA macro?

```
 strFolderPath = BrowseForFolder(\\SERVER1\g\VCI JOBS\)
```

Comment: maybe double quotation marks? strFolderPath = BrowseForFolder("\SERVER1\g\VCI JOBS")

Comment: yes, the double quotes were missing. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the Shell object. You first need to get the shell object before you can use the `BrowseForFolder` method of it.

EXAMPLE:

```
With New Shell
    strFolderPath = .BrowseForFolder("\\SERVER1\g\VCI JOBS\")
End With
```

Notice the dot `.` before the method. That means I am using the shell object from the with block.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/shell-browseforfolder